# Format an SQL query in Python without executing it

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, prepared-statement, code-injection

Python has all sort of libraries to interface with databases, which provide a nice way to build SQL queries without worrying about SQL injections. For instance, with sqlite3:

```
for t in [('2006-03-28', 'BUY', 'IBM', 1000, 45.00),
          ('2006-04-05', 'BUY', 'MSOFT', 1000, 72.00),
          ('2006-04-06', 'SELL', 'IBM', 500, 53.00),
         ]:
    c.execute('insert into stocks values (?,?,?,?,?)', t)
```

The trouble is, I don't want to *execute* the query, I just want to format it and get the query as a string. I guess I could escape things myself, but it's not a very elegant solution. There has to be a way to get the formatted queries without actually connecting to a database and running them.

(The context is that I'm writing a filter which prepares a series of SQL statements from the input, but I don't want to run them on a specific database, just save them for later.)

Comment: I don't believe that's something Python is doing... isn't the ability to use parameters handled at the driver level?  i.e., I would use the exact same SQL code in ASP.Net or Java to talk to the database.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> There has to be a way to get the formatted queries without actually connecting to a database and running them

Not really.

The RDBMS handles this internally with "prepared queries" and "bind variables".  The "formatted" doesn't actually exist.  Anywhere.

Comment: Woops, I didn't knew about this at all, I though this was only a convenient way to take care of escaping. As it turns out, this question is irrelevant; I learnt something new today. :-) If someone else was confused by this, see: https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Prepared_statement